# no jvm found issue after update to Java 8

Tags: install4j

I have install4j 5 and when I tried to launch the app I get this:

"No JVM can be found on your system. Please define EXE4J_JAVA_HOME to point to an installed 64-bit..."

I recently updated JAVA from 7 to 8 so the path was changed.  I was looking at the environment variables but did not see the EXE4J_JAVA_HOME property.

Any ideas on where to find this property so I can point it to the proper location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install4j 5 IDE needs a Java 7 JRE to run. You can download the installer with a bundled JRE.

Comment: Yes it requires specific Java 7 JRE